# Efficiently extract specific table from 403MB (yes I have that right) html file

Tags: java, html, performance, parsing, jsoup

#### Question:

- What is an efficient approach to extract all tables from an HTML file the HTML is nearly half a gigabyte in size?

My current approach which works fine for files < 100MB is:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(full_html);
    Elements html_tables = doc.select("table");
```

`JSoup.parse` performs horribly though for 400MB files. Can I write my own HTML tokenizer to rapidly extract the tables? Any recommendations?

#### Background:

- I'm extracting an HTML table, identified by matching its text with a regular expression, from a broader HTML file embedded in an SEC filing.
- Currently: I use JSoup to parse the HTML. Then I iterate over tables looking for candidates that match my criteria.
- The problem is that starting in about 2014, some of the SEC filings have gotten stupid large. Example (403 megabyte file!):

  -rw-r--r--  1 mgunn  staff   403M 0000065984-14-000065.txt
- Calling `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(full_html)`, part of my current method, takes minutes and/or runs out of memory.
- I need to do this on file after file after file (several of them > 100MB), so I need to write/use something fairly robust and efficient.

Comment: It is rather large.  401k I could understand.

Comment: What would happen if you split the HTML file into smaller files and simply close any open tags and re-open them in the next file?

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, the size is why I am having a problem :/.

Comment: You want a stream parser, not a tree parser, like https://code.google.com/p/htmlstreamparser/

Comment: Or alternatively use the SAX parser to extract the data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the original post, you should not try to load such huge documents with a DOM based parser, since this will take a lot of memory. Instead, you should look into alternatives which are well established. The keywords here is SAX, which stands for "Simple API for XML Parsing". There are several Java alternatives:

- [tagsoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) - tries its best to make sens out of messy/incomplete html
- [nekohtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) - allround html parser.

The handling is somewhat different from DOM based parsing, but manageable.